# How to open new Window on button press event in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I wish to open new window on click of Button in kivy ...
What I am currently trying is to create an instance of another class which inherits `kivy.App`.

```
class SettingScreen(App):
    pass

class Screen(Widget):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    def btn_touch_up(self):
       print("Touch Up ")
       SettingScreen().run()

class TouchApp(App):
def build(self):
    return Screen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   TouchApp().run()
```

what happens after clicking button is that title of my window changed, But Window Does not went blank.that is my existing widgets are still on window

touch.ky

```
<Screen>:
btn:btn
Label:
    id: msg
    text: "Hii"
    color: 1,0,0,1

    pos_hint: {"top":0.8}
Button:
    id: btn
    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
    text: "Touch Me"
    on_touch_up: root.btn_touch_up()
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one `App` running in `Kivy`. Have a look at [ModalView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.modalview.html#module-kivy.uix.modalview) or [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html).

Comment: Or perhaps, consider using [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to have two App class in one Kivy app or Python script.

We will separate the `SettingScreen` into another Kivy app, and use [popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to launch `SettingScreen`.

## Example

### touch.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Screen>:
    btn:btn
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: msg
        text: "Hi"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        pos_hint: {"top":0.8}

    Button:
        id: btn
        size_hint: 0.2,0.2
        text: "Touch Me"
        on_release:  root.btn_touch_up()

""")


class Screen(BoxLayout):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn_touch_up(self):
        print("Touch Up ")
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        process = Popen(['python3', 'settings.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)


class TouchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TouchApp().run()
```

### settings.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = Builder.load_string("""
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Setting Screen'
        Button:
            text: 'Exit'
            on_release: app.stop()
""")


class SettingScreen(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SettingScreen().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result - 2 Kivy Apps running]